# Combining voices while considering their start time

Tags: ffmpeg

## Combine voices and add them to a video

I have this FFMPEG command to:

1. Remove current video audio.
2. Combine some voices and add them to the video.

```bash
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i voice1.mp3 -i voice2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a] [2:a] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0" -c:v copy -an vid.mkv
```

The above command works great.

## Each voice has a start time

I have a new requirement. Each voice should start at its own specific *start time*. Like:

1. Voice 1 starts at `2 sec` of the video.
2. Voice 2 starts at `1 sec` of the video.

How can I modify my FFMPEG command so that each voice would be at its own proper *start time*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob I didn't notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this approach, and it works:

```bash
ffmpeg -i vid-in.mkv -i voice1.wav -i voice2.wav -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=5000|5000[a1]; [2:a]adelay=10000|10000[a2]; [a1][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=0"  -c:v copy -an vid.mkv
```

I was suggested here: https://poe.com/s/9po0ZSqwk6PjskQyD5ou